# wordpress not saving form code in code editor

Tags: forms, html, html-editor, paypal

I'm sure this question has been asked a thousand times, but when I search, or post a question with the above title, no answer is presented.

A few weeks ago, I was able to save Paypal form code into the Wordpress paged editor's `code` tab.

Now, when I try to save the Paypal form code, it is stripped back to:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Embedding PayPal code into the text editor is always a little risky due to the layout of html elements 'PayPal style' vs the layout of html elements 'Wordpress content style'... both are trying to 'think' for you a little bit to make your life easier, but as a result the formatting can go whacky.

As I'm sure many others have answered previously, it's best to insert this into your theme templates. eg. page.php or single.php etc, to maintain a tighter control on the display.

Comment: I guess you're right, but doesn't explain why it was working a few weeks ago.

Comment: Wordpress won't have changed its behaviour from a few weeks ago. If you flick between the 'visual' and 'text' editor your code can alter slightly - perhaps this is what has happened for you? This is well-discussed in places such as: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115500/switch-between-visual-and-html-tab-freely Perhaps you kept it on 'text' previously, this time flicked back to 'visual'? In general, as mentioned, it's simply not a 'safe' method to embed code via the text editor, this is designed to be used only for text and basic html.